# Anniversaries with Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

If anyone has attempted anything vaguely anniversary date based in Salesforce, it usually has resorted in a need to hit up Workflows and Apex Triggers to perform the action.

Process Builder can actually handle this without needing a line of code. For the code adverse, it could take anything up to a couple of weeks of heartache and frustration as you get to grips with a foreign language, understanding the logic but unable to battle the syntax and wrangle fragments of google searches into something that matches your business processes. With this solution, a day to make, a day to wait and test and you've made the solution with incredible flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

My personal situation was the need to send an email to all the related contacts to a Contract on anniversaries.

Process Builder allows you to do this with a few processes and a suite of custom fields.

The first pair of fields are:

*Current Anniversary*

*Next Anniversary*

Current Anniversary would be updated to equal the Contract Start Date, you'd allow this to be amended by process prior to Contract becoming Active. This takes into account any last minute edits before the record is locked. On Contract Activation, it should update to read Next Anniversary using a process.

Next Anniversary is an Add Days/Months/Years formula field (there are a multitude of established solutions to calculate this) - which points at the Current Anniversary.

The next pair of fields are:

*Process Builder Date*

*TODAY()*

TODAY() is simply a formula field reading TODAY()

Process Builder Date updates to TODAY() with a process that runs on record creation.

A single process runs in the background that runs on Process Builder Date = TODAY(). The action is a scheduled update to make Process Builder Date = TODAY 1 day later (this will be a full 24hrs later, not on the crossing of midnight). This one field will then perpetually update every day. If you want to be tidy, you can insert a get out clause which ceases the update once it passes Contract End Date.

With this perpetually updating field, you can then create any process tied to it. In this case it would be Anniversary Date <= Process Builder Date. At that point you update Anniversary Date to Next Anniversary and perform any other actions you wish. For me, it was a process that navigated through the Account ID to Account, where I could select Contacts and update a "Send Email" checkbox on all related Contacts in one fell swoop. In turn, there is a Process there waiting for that box to be ticked so it can perform an Email Alert towards the given record before unchecking the checkbox ready for next time.

For testing purposes, you can add in a "Post To Chatter" action to ensure your various processes and updates are working. Obviously disable this for the live roll out unless you want a massive series of records spamming you with updates every day.